# SQLite problems in Android, "no such table" error

Tags: java, android, sql, sqlite

I've searched around stack overflow for similar problems but none of them seems to apply or work when it comes to my problem. I have an app that creates a SQLite database, which is fully functional when it comes to the table "LOGIN", but everything else just crashes the app. My database consists of users along with projects and tasks that users can create, so when I try to list every project done by a specific user I get a "no such table" error even though the table absolutely exists and it works with LOGIN. I first thought I had an old database still in the cache, but I've tried factory resetting the device two times which wipes out the entire database but the error still persists. What's wrong?

The Database Helper:

```
package com.example.tasksketchgui;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

public class DataBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper
{
public DataBaseHelper(Context context, String name,CursorFactory factory, int version) 
{
           super(context, name, factory, version);
}
// Called when no database exists in disk and the helper class needs
// to create a new one.
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase _db) 
{
        _db.execSQL(LoginDataBaseAdapter.DATABASE_CREATE);

}
// Called when there is a database version mismatch meaning that the version
// of the database on disk needs to be upgraded to the current version.
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase _db, int _oldVersion, int _newVersion) 
{
        // Log the version upgrade.
        Log.w("TaskDBAdapter", "Upgrading from version " +_oldVersion + " to " +_newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");

        // Upgrade the existing database to conform to the new version. Multiple
        // previous versions can be handled by comparing _oldVersion and _newVersion
        // values.
        // The simplest case is to drop the old table and create a new one.
        _db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + "TEMPLATE");
        // Create a new one.
        onCreate(_db);
}

}
```

Here is an adapter which I use to access the database.

```
package com.example.tasksketchgui;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import com.example.tasksketchgui.sqlite.model.ProjectEntry;
import com.example.tasksketchgui.sqlite.model.UserEntry;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;

public class LoginDataBaseAdapter 
{
    static final String DATABASE_NAME = "login.db";
    static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    public static final int NAME_COLUMN = 1;
    // TODO: Create public field for each column in your table.
    //Column for all tables
    static final String KEY_ID = "_id";
    static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
    static final String KEY_DEADLINE = "deadline";
    static final String KEY_USER_ID = "user_id";
    static final String KEY_PROJECT_ID = "project_id";
    //Column names for login
    static final String KEY_USER_PASSWORD = "PASSWORD"; 
    static final String KEY_USER_NAME = "USERNAME";
    //Column names for user_task
    static final String KEY_TASK_ID = "task_id";

    //Table names
    static final String TABLE_PROJECT = "projects";
    static final String TABLE_TASK = "tasks";
    static final String TABLE_TASK_USER = "task_user";
    static final String TABLE_PROJECT_USER = "project_user";

    //Create table for projects
    static final String CREATE_TABLE_PROJECT = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_PROJECT + " ("
            + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + KEY_NAME + " TEXT, "
            + KEY_DEADLINE + " TEXT, " + KEY_USER_ID + " INTEGER" + ") ;";
    //Create table for tasks
    static final String CREATE_TABLE_TASK = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_TASK + " ("
            + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + KEY_NAME + " TEXT, "
            + KEY_PROJECT_ID + " INTEGER, " + KEY_DEADLINE + " DATETIME" + ") ;";
    //Create table for taskUsers
    static final String CREATE_TABLE_TASK_USER = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_TASK_USER + " ("
            + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "+ KEY_TASK_ID + 
            " INTEGER, " + KEY_USER_ID + "INTEGER" + ") ;";
    //Create table for projectUsers
    static final String CREATE_TABLE_PROJECT_USER = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_PROJECT_USER + " ("
            + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + KEY_PROJECT_ID + " INTEGER, "
            + KEY_USER_ID + " INTEGER" + ") ;";

    // SQL Statement to create a new database.
    static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "create table IF NOT EXISTS "+"LOGIN"+
            "( " +"ID"+" integer primary key autoincrement,"+ "USERNAME  text,PASSWORD text); "
            + CREATE_TABLE_PROJECT + "; " + CREATE_TABLE_TASK + ";" + CREATE_TABLE_TASK_USER
            + ";" + CREATE_TABLE_PROJECT_USER + ";";
    // Variable to hold the database instance
    public  SQLiteDatabase db;
    // Context of the application using the database.
    private final Context context;
    // Database open/upgrade helper
    private DataBaseHelper dbHelper;
    public  LoginDataBaseAdapter(Context _context) 
    {
        context = _context;
        dbHelper = new DataBaseHelper(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);


    }
    public  LoginDataBaseAdapter open() throws SQLException 
    {
        db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();

        return this;
    }
    public void close()
    {
        db.close();
    }

    public  SQLiteDatabase getDatabaseInstance()
    {
        return db;
    }

    public void insertEntry(UserEntry user)
    {
       ContentValues newValues = new ContentValues();
        // Assign values for each row.
        newValues.put("USERNAME", user.getUserName());
        newValues.put("PASSWORD", user.getPassword());


        db.insert("LOGIN", null, newValues);
        ///Toast.makeText(context, "Reminder Is Successfully Saved", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    public void insertEntry(String userName,String password)
    {
       ContentValues newValues = new ContentValues();
        // Assign values for each row.
        newValues.put("USERNAME", userName);
        newValues.put("PASSWORD",password);


        db.insert("LOGIN", null, newValues);
        ///Toast.makeText(context, "Reminder Is Successfully Saved", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    public int deleteUser(String UserName)
    {
        //String id=String.valueOf(ID);
        String where="USERNAME=?";
        int numberOFEntriesDeleted= db.delete("LOGIN", where, new String[]{UserName}) ;
       // Toast.makeText(context, "Number fo Entry Deleted Successfully : "+numberOFEntriesDeleted, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return numberOFEntriesDeleted;
    }    
    public String getSinlgeUserPassword(String userName)
    {
        Cursor cursor=db.query("LOGIN", null, " USERNAME=?", new String[]{userName}, null, null, null);
        if(cursor.getCount()<1) // UserName Not Exist
        {
            cursor.close();
            return "NOT EXIST";
        }
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        String password= cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("PASSWORD"));
        cursor.close();
        return password;                
    }

    //Returns all users in the database
    public List<UserEntry> getAllUser(){
        List<UserEntry> users = new ArrayList<UserEntry>();

        String query = "SELECT * FROM LOGIN";
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);

        //If there's at least one entry
        if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
            do{
                UserEntry user = new UserEntry();
                user.setUserName(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("USERNAME")));
                user.setPassword(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("PASSWORD")));

                //Add to list
                users.add(user);
            }while(cursor.moveToNext());
            cursor.close();
        }

        return users;
    }

    //Returns all projects from the user
    public List<ProjectEntry> getProjectsFromUser(String userName){
        List<ProjectEntry> projects = new ArrayList<ProjectEntry>();

        String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_PROJECT + " pr," +
        "LOGIN lg, " + TABLE_PROJECT_USER + " pu WHERE LOGIN.USERNAME = '"
        + userName + "' AND pr." + KEY_ID + " = pu." + KEY_PROJECT_ID +
        " AND pu." + KEY_USER_ID + " = LOGIN.ID";

        Cursor c = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        if(c.moveToFirst()){
            do{
                ProjectEntry project = new ProjectEntry();
                project.setId(c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_ID)));
                project.setName(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_NAME)));
                project.setUserId(c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_USER_ID)));
                project.setDeadline(c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(KEY_DEADLINE)));

                projects.add(project);
            }while(c.moveToNext());
        }

        return projects;
    }

    //Create project
    public long createProject(ProjectEntry project, UserEntry user){
        ContentValues valuesProject = new ContentValues();
        ContentValues valuesProjectUser = new ContentValues();

        valuesProject.put(KEY_USER_ID, user.getId());
        valuesProject.put(KEY_NAME, project.getName());
        valuesProject.put(KEY_DEADLINE, project.getDeadline().toString());

        long id = db.insert(TABLE_PROJECT, null, valuesProject);

        valuesProjectUser.put(KEY_PROJECT_ID, id);
        valuesProjectUser.put(KEY_USER_ID, user.getId());
        //Return the projects id, so that it can be found
        return id;
    }

    public long createProject(ProjectEntry project, long user){
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

        values.put(KEY_USER_ID, user);
        values.put(KEY_NAME, project.getName());
        values.put(KEY_DEADLINE, project.getDeadline().toString());

        long id = db.insert(TABLE_PROJECT, null, values);
        //Return the projects id, so that it can be found
        return id;
    }

    public void  updateEntry(String userName,String password)
    {
        // Define the updated row content.
        ContentValues updatedValues = new ContentValues();
        // Assign values for each row.
        updatedValues.put("USERNAME", userName);
        updatedValues.put("PASSWORD",password);

        String where="USERNAME = ?";
        db.update("LOGIN",updatedValues, where, new String[]{userName});               
    }        
}
```

This is the lines of code calling the query.

```
    loginDataBaseAdapter=new LoginDataBaseAdapter(this);
    loginDataBaseAdapter=loginDataBaseAdapter.open();

    //Fill list of projects
    List<ProjectEntry> projects = new ArrayList<ProjectEntry>();
    projects = loginDataBaseAdapter.getProjectsFromUser("pontan");
```

And here's the stack trace:

> 08-08 15:28:07.101: D/libEGL(2213): loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libEGL_POWERVR_SGX540_120.so
>   08-08 15:28:07.101: D/libEGL(2213): loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_POWERVR_SGX540_120.so
>   08-08 15:28:07.109: D/libEGL(2213): loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_POWERVR_SGX540_120.so
>   08-08 15:28:07.187: D/OpenGLRenderer(2213): Enabling debug mode 0
>   08-08 15:28:07.312: D/dalvikvm(2213): GC_CONCURRENT freed 114K, 2% free 9097K/9240K, paused 6ms+17ms, total 53ms
>   08-08 15:28:38.179: D/dalvikvm(2213): GC_CONCURRENT freed 152K, 2% free 9341K/9520K, paused 2ms+5ms, total 23ms
>   08-08 15:28:39.695: E/SQLiteLog(2213): (1) no such table: projects
>   08-08 15:28:39.695: D/AndroidRuntime(2213): Shutting down VM
>   08-08 15:28:39.695: W/dalvikvm(2213): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41336930)
>   08-08 15:28:39.710: E/AndroidRuntime(2213): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   08-08 15:28:39.710: E/AndroidRuntime(2213): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.tasksketchgui/com.example.tasksketchgui.ProjectListActivity}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: projects (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM projects pr,LOGIN lg, project_user pu WHERE LOGIN.USERNAME = 'pontan' AND pr._id = pu.project_id AND pu.user_id = LOGIN.ID
>   08-08 15:28:39.710: E/AndroidRuntime(2213):   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
>   08-08 15:28:39.710: E/AndroidRuntime(2213):   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
>   08-08 15:28:39.710: E/AndroidRuntime(2213):   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
>   08-08 15:28:39.710: E/AndroidRuntime(2213):   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
>   08-08 15:28:39.710: E/AndroidRuntime(2213):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>   08-08 15:28:39.710: E/AndroidRuntime(2213):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>   08-08 15:28:39.710: E/AndroidRuntime(2213):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
>   08-08 15:28:39.710: E/AndroidRuntime(2213):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   08-08 15:28:39.710: E/AndroidRuntime(2213):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>   08-08 15:28:39.710: E/AndroidRuntime(2213):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
>   08-08 15:28:39.710: E/AndroidRuntime(2213):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
>   08-08 15:28:39.710: E/AndroidRuntime(2213):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>   08-08 15:28:39.710: E/AndroidRuntime(2213): Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: projects (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM projects pr,LOGIN lg, project_user pu WHERE LOGIN.USERNAME = 'pontan' AND pr._id = pu.project_id AND pu.user_id = LOGIN.ID
>   08-08 15:28:39.710: E/AndroidRuntime(2213):   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
>   08-08 15:28:39.710: E/AndroidRuntime(2213):   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:882)
>   08-08 15:28:39.710: E/AndroidRuntime(2213):   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:493)
>   08-08 15:28:39.710: E/AndroidRuntime(2213):   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
>   08-08 15:28:39.710: E/AndroidRuntime(2213):   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
>   08-08 15:28:39.710: E/AndroidRuntime(2213):   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.(SQLiteQuery.java:37)
>   08-08 15:28:39.710: E/AndroidRuntime(2213):   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:44)
>   08-08 15:28:39.710: E/AndroidRuntime(2213):   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1314)
>   08-08 15:28:39.710: E/AndroidRuntime(2213):   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(SQLiteDatabase.java:1253)
>   08-08 15:28:39.710: E/AndroidRuntime(2213):   at com.example.tasksketchgui.LoginDataBaseAdapter.getProjectsFromUser(LoginDataBaseAdapter.java:167)
>   08-08 15:28:39.710: E/AndroidRuntime(2213):   at com.example.tasksketchgui.ProjectListActivity.onCreate(ProjectListActivity.java:34)
>   08-08 15:28:39.710: E/AndroidRuntime(2213):   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
>   08-08 15:28:39.710: E/AndroidRuntime(2213):   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
>   08-08 15:28:39.710: E/AndroidRuntime(2213):   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
>   08-08 15:28:39.710: E/AndroidRuntime(2213):   ... 11 more
>   08-08 15:28:42.421: I/Process(2213): Sending signal. PID: 2213 SIG: 9
>   08-08 15:28:42.656: D/libEGL(2253): loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libEGL_POWERVR_SGX540_120.so
>   08-08 15:28:42.664: D/libEGL(2253): loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_POWERVR_SGX540_120.so
>   08-08 15:28:42.664: D/libEGL(2253): loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_POWERVR_SGX540_120.so
>   08-08 15:28:42.742: D/OpenGLRenderer(2253): Enabling debug mode 0
>   08-08 15:28:42.765: D/dalvikvm(2253): GC_CONCURRENT freed 121K, 2% free 9097K/9248K, paused 3ms+6ms, total 24ms

And yes, a lot of this is code is completely ripped from a tutorial, along with comments, and will be rewritten soon. How the table "LOGIN" is created sure is random when considering the rest.

I appreciate all the help I could get! Thanks! :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`execSQL()` can only execute one statement at a time.

Do not combine your SQL into a single `DATABASE_CREATE`string separated by `;`. Instead, `execSQL()` the individual SQL statements separately.

Also uninstall your app so the old database with incorrect tables gets removed.

Answer (score 0):

Have you added the tables all at once?
If you have not removed the app and reinstalled it, the onCreate of your SQLiteOpenHelper will not be called again.

Comment: Yes, I added all the tables at once, with a semicolon separating the create queries.

I have not only tried uninstalling the app and reinstalling it, I've done a complete factory reset twice, uninstalling every single app and clearing it of all user generated data. I mentioned this in the original question, and the error still persists.

Comment: `with a semicolon separating the create queries` - which is perfectly **useless**, since SQLite simply **ignores** the semicolon (as Iaalto just said in his answer, right now).

Answer (score 0):

you are using LOGIN lg, and using as `LOGIN.USERNAME` , this would also throw you **`no such column exception`** so instead of referencing it as

```
SELECT * FROM projects pr,LOGIN lg, project_user pu WHERE LOGIN.USERNAME = 'pontan' AND pr._id = pu.project_id AND pu.user_id = LOGIN.ID
```

use

```
SELECT * FROM projects pr,LOGIN lg, project_user pu WHERE lg.USERNAME = 'pontan' AND pr._id = pu.project_id AND pu.user_id = lg.ID
```

your query should be :

```
String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_PROJECT + " pr," +
        "LOGIN lg, " + TABLE_PROJECT_USER + " pu WHERE lg.USERNAME = '"
        + userName + "' AND pr." + KEY_ID + " = pu." + KEY_PROJECT_ID +
        " AND pu." + KEY_USER_ID + " = lg.ID";
```